# How to read rows from Lucene.Net's index files

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, lucene, lucene.net

I am using Lunece.net 2.0.5 version.
I want to open and display all the records in the index file in a grid (table) format in an ASP.NET web application, and also provide edit option for each cell in that grid.
But I don't know how to read each row from Index file.

I used code below-

```
   private List<String> GetIndexTerms(string indexFolder)
        {
            List<String> termlist = new List<string>();
            IndexReader reader = IndexReader.Open(indexFolder, false);
            TermEnum terms = reader.Terms();
            while (terms.Next())
            {
                Term term = terms.Term();
                String termText = term.Text();
                int frequency = reader.DocFreq(term);
                termlist.Add(termText);
            }
            reader.Close();
            return termlist;
        }
```

but it returns list of each term and here I am unable to aggregate data by each row (record).

Let me know if there is way to read file by each row or I need to update version of Lucene that I am currently using.

Also please provide any links to Lucene.net's better documentation websites.

Comment: What should be the two axis? Term and Document? And the value the frequency? That will be huge.

Comment: Lucene is not a row and column database and does not support updates of individual values. You probably need to use a relational database.

Comment: I googled this one for you -- see [here](http://www.jguru.com/faq/view.jsp?EID=587213). Another approach could be te use MatchAllDocsQuery, but then you get the complete array of all doc ids, and in the approach described in the post linked to above you get an enum. Oh yeah, and follow the advice from one of the replies -- use maxDoc(), not numDocs().

Comment: Tass, I want all the fields on x axis and each documents (records) on y axis

Comment: Thank you Marko, I will try with this.

Comment: This also maybe of help: ["Multi Query Search Using Lucene.NET"](http://surinder.computing-studio.com/post/2010/12/13/Multi-Query-Search-Using-LuceneNET.aspx). This post show an example on how you would search an index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read all the records/rows (`document`s in Lucene terminology) directly from the index without  searching

```
var reader =  IndexReader.Open(dir);
for (int i = 0; i < reader.MaxDoc(); i++)
{
    if (reader.IsDeleted(i)) continue;

    Document d =  reader.Document(i);
    var fieldValuePairs =  d.GetFields()
                            .Select(f => new { 
                                  Name = f.Name(), 
                                  Value = f.StringValue() })
                            .ToArray();
}
```

PS: v2.0.5 is very old. try latest & greatest [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/download.html)